# Use mean value theorem on $f(x) = x^{1/5}$, to show that $2< \sqrt[5]{33}<2.0125$

Tags: calculus, inequality

The problem specifically aks us to use mean value theorem on the interval $[32, 33]$

It has always puzzled me that mean value theorem can be used to prove Inequalities.

Can anyone show how mean value theorem can be used to prove Inequalities like these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mean value theorem, in your situation, says that
$$\frac{{\root5\of{33}}-2}{33-32}=\frac{1}{5c^{4/5}}$$
for some $c$ between $32$ and $33$.  This can be rewritten
$${\root5\of{33}}=2+\frac{1}{5c^{4/5}}\ .$$
Since $c>32$ we have
$$\frac{1}{c^{4/5}}<\frac{1}{32^{4/5}}=\frac{1}{2^4}\ .$$
See if you can finish the problem for yourself.